# Can you connect a self hosted Confluence Wiki to a self hosted Gitlab Server (Tier: free)?

Tags: gitlab, confluence

I know you can use integrations for cloud-based Confluence Sites, however the documentation does not indicate that possibility for self-hosted instances. Is there a way to connect without using the cloud solution, which is not an option for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can add external links (as I ended up doing) to a project and thus can refer to a documentation via adding a confluence-link in the "external wiki"-section (Project→ Settings→Integration→External wiki). Make sure to use the link from the "share"-button, otherwise the link breaks on renaming the page. Do note that this will be just a link in the project-sidebar:

[image: External wiki as shown on GitLab]

If you have your documentation only in Confluence, you can disable the gitlab-internal wiki (per project), by going to Project→ Settings→General→Visibility and toggling "Wiki" off. So you can avoid having two wiki-items in your sidebar.

Some time ago the UI changed, the external wiki is now hidden under the point "Plan", but it can be pinned to the top:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

- Use of a 3rd party add-on (e.g. like [this](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1216286/confluence-gitlab-connector?hosting=server&tab=overview))
- Developing a [custom functionality to connect to your local GitLab server](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-plugin-guide/). It will depend on the AD you use (internal or ADFS, etc.).
- If you do not want to use any 3rd party apps, you can create any functionality in Java as [plugins](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-plugin-guide/).

Comment: Do note that with self-hosted Confluence getting discontinued, so is its marketplace for 3rd party add-ons.